# SSIS Case Statement Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate a column called 'Duplicate' with a Y or N. If the student has enrolled for a class in that term and in that career it should be marked as N or else it should be marked as Yes. The parent table has 40 million rows. And the SQL I have is

```
Select Duplicate =  Case when e.EMPLID is null then 'Y'
                  when e1.EMPLID is null then 'Y'
                  else 'N'
                  end               
from F_Student_Programs_05 b
left outer join PS_STUDENT_ENRL e on b.EMPLID = e.EMPLID and
                                    b.Term_Code = e.STRM and
                                    e.ACAD_CAREER = 'EXED'

left outer join PS_STUDENT_ENRL e1 on b.EMPLID = e1.EMPLID and
                                    b.Term_Code = e1.STRM and
                                    e1.ACAD_CAREER = 'CNED'
```

if I run this code in a dataflow task, it is getting stuck after delivering 8,192 rows in SSIS. Could someone give some suggestion on how to make it work? 
FYI - I use MS SQL,
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean 'getting stuck'?

Comment: It delivers 8,192 rows and it keeps spinning but the row count being delivered does not increase nor the task finishes execution

Comment: Is it possible it's timing out? 40 million rows is a lot to return.

Comment: The task that builds the 40 million row table runs for 20 mins, So I am not sure if this is a time out issue.

Comment: If you have a lot more ACAD_CAREER codes, you could try creating a temp table for each code (EXED, CNED) to simplify the joins.

Comment: Thank you, will try this method